# Is there anything like a websocket but doesn't require a framework like node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I'm working on a simple betting game and would love to update values live. But I've already written most of my app in jquery and javascript and it has a mysql database that was set up by another developer. I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to live update my site when bets come in, without using ajax calls or having to learn a new framework? Right now the bets are sent to a url which updates json. Any help would be great! I've researched the topic and all I can seem to find is websockets which only seem compatible with Node.

Comment: Websockets require a server-side application, but that doesn't have to be running under node.js.  What is your server-side technology?  (php/asp.net etc.)

Comment: @Archer Right now I am working with another developer and he is using PHP for the server side code.

Comment: As @Archer states, it doesn't have to be node. There must be some server side language acting as an intermediary between your JS and database. They don't link together directly.

Comment: There's several Websocket libraries for PHP. A 10 second Google search found this: http://socketo.me/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API This might prove useful to you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I guess my main question is, how would I use JS on the front end and PHP to do the websockets?

Comment: Another 10 seconds in Google: http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firebase` it let you do realtime things like websocket, without needs a server, or to maintain a database. Using your frontend JavaScript Knowledge.

More information:

- https://firebase.google.com/